# How to get IDFV with ActionScript?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I want to get IDFV value in my ActionScript code.

How would I do it?

p.s. I have ANE to get IDFA, but I cannot find any solution for IDFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the vendor ID using our (distriqt) Application ANE as below:

```
var vendorId:String = Application.service.device.uniqueId( IDType.VENDOR );
```

It is available here: http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Application

Comment: Thanks for the support. Let me know if you need anything else. Cheers